# Как скрыть элемент при появлении disabled="disabled"?

Tags: html, css

Необходимо чтобы disabled блоку присваивался:

```
display: none;
```

Не disabled блоку:

```
display: block;
```

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Можете предоставить контекст в виде примера кода?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать селектор по свойству:

```css
div {
  display: block;
}

div[disabled="disabled"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div disabled="disabled">disabled</div>
<div>active</div>
```